# Could our REST API us a datestamp to represent a "fake" resource instead of an id?

Tags: rest, identifier, api-design

We are creating a REST API to allow our clients to fetch their licensed content and I am trying to determine whether it is possible to conceal some internal complexity from our clients by creating a resource (a `delivery`) that would then be mapped to a collection of internal resources (many "batches").

**Our business process** dictates that when we prepare content for a client it is currently separated by content-type, and we call sets of content-types "batches" (though we'll change this process in the next 12-24 months to better align with the concept of "deliveries").  Batches are historically unrelated to each other except in the mind of the curators.  Curators generate xml files for all the batches and bundle them together in an email to clients, thereby providing the impression that all the content is part of a single delivery.

**The problem** is that for a client who wants to retrieve content for a specific delivery (say December 2014 or May 2016) using our internal "batches" system forces the client to determine which batches are associated with the desired delivery.  **The alternative** I'm imagining is that we create "deliveries" as a resource which, behind the scenes, would be mapped to all the constituent  batches.

**The sticking point** is that since we don't have an internal representation of a  `delivery`(yet) we don't have a preexisting id to key off of.  However, the `due-date` of the delivery is a reliable, unique identifier.  It is meaningful to the client and could be used to associate batches with the `delivery`.

**So my question is:** can we use a due-date in place of an id?  Something like `/v0/deliveries/20160530` to retrieve the content delivered on May 30th, 2016?  (It has been suggested that this might violate RESTful principals.)

Answer (score 2):

REST doesn't say anything about what URLs should look like. Any unique identifier is fine. Some APIs use UUIDs because they don't want to reveal the number of a type of resource they have.

Answer (score 0):

**This sounds like something that might be better presented as a kind of search**. For example, if your batches can be accessed at `/v0/batches/(id)`, you might use `/v0/batches?delivered=20160530` to get a list of the batches delivered on that date. This could be extended in the future to allow searches on other criteria.

Comment: Given that batches are otherwise not a meaningful concept to our clients, do you see a compelling reason to keep them?  It seems that `/v0/batches?delivered=20160530` returns the same content as `/v0/deliveries/20160530`.